# How to make video player in swift?

Tags: swift, video, avplayer

I am making video player in swift. I need add some custom buttons and functionality for standard video player:
1. Playing video from url (server)
2. Showing indicator while loading video like in VK
3. Add custom buttons to control (stop,pause buttons)

I try to use AVKit/AVPlayerViewController, but i cant understand how i can implement my tasks there. Can you give some advise, which is the better way to do this?